# How can I use the flask.Response in my JS code?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, vue.js

I've been trying for a while now, but I failed to manage to get my hands on the returned value from my backend, on my frontend.

Here's my code:

```
def add_New_Form():
    resp = Response("something") #Note that the response value is a string
    return resp
```

And I want to be able to use it on my frontend (I'm using Vue). I can't jsonify `resp` because Response is not jsonifyable. I've tried:

```
var name = this.$http.post(*My request here*)
```

But this doesn't work as I expect it to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never handling the response. As you're using `this.$http` which is likely `vue-resource` your request returns a `Promise` which you can then chain from:

```
this.$http.post(*My request here*)
  .then( response => {
      console.log(response.data) // it's your string
  })
```